# Refactoring gradle test class so that test inside can be run in parallel

Tags: scala, gradle, testing

I have some integration test that are run by gradle in parallel but one of the test classes is significantly slower than others - not much can be done as it iterates in for loop on every element in list ( and it will get bigger ).

As I learned gradle can only parallelise  on class level.

The easiest solution would be to refactor every element in list as a class with communal base class - but that would mean that I would need to create a new class for every element in list and for every new added one and I don't feel good about it.

Is there a way to do it better ? For example make scala create runtime classes that would be recognised by gradle ? Maybe parallelise on scala level ? I tried using scala parallel collections and making list par but didn't work - I assume I was missing something.

Here is an example of the class:

```
class TestWithForEach  {

  val reports: Se[String] = Seq(
      "name",
      "name2",
      ....
)
    
  reports.foreach(reportName => {
    it should s"generate $reportName" in {
      generateReport(reportName)
    }
  })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of workarounds I have found is using sparkTest.ParallelTestExecution trait for the Class in question. This is slightly slower than doing new classes for every element so I'm still searching for alternatives.

Found out about scala reflections and it seems that it could maybe work ? Didn't had luck using them yet